# How do I play sound when page is updated

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it even possible to play a sound when the size of the web page change. I will be adding new text to this page daily. If the user refresh the page I would like to play a sound only if the bytes of the page change. Thanks.

Comment: “If the bytes of the page change.” …What?!

Comment: If I was to add a 3 megabyte picture to a webpage, the bytes size of the page would change , or would it not?

Comment: It would not. The size of the page is the size of the page, not the assets associated with it.

Comment: What if I add a lot of text to the page. Would not the more text I add increase the page size?

Comment: I think you're approaching the problem the wrong way. You need a different metric to test against. You could, for example, store the timestamp of the last update in a cookie. If the user's cookie does not match the timestamp of the latest update, play a sound and update their cookie.

Comment: I basically just retyped Umbrella's answer without realising. You should probably choose his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.  If you set a cookie on the page to track the last datetime the user requested the page on (or the file size at that time) and add an update datetime to the page, you can compare whether the pages was updated since a user's last visit and trigger an event.

The key here is that the page itself doesn't know how big it used to be, but if you can store that information in a cookie, you can detect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too much for what you're doing but it's the best audio library I know: http://createjs.com/#!/SoundJS